# java - All possible combinations of an array into one method

Tags: java

I am looking a way to put the method `static void combinationUtil()` function into `public static void main (String[] args)`.

I mean to remove the method `static void combinationUtil()` then the whole class only got one method `public static void main (String[] args)`, or How can I print array data[] in `public static void main (String[] args)`

```
class permutation {

    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, int index, int r){
    if (index == r){
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++){
            System.out.print(data[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        return;
    }


    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7};
    int r = 5;
    int n = arr.length;
    int data[]=new int[r];
    int start=0,end=n-1,index=0;
    combinationUtil(arr, data, start, end, index, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to take a look at this article, it might help: http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html. Essentially, you have a method is working by recursion (combinationUtil), and so it's not trivial to simply move its logic into main; instead, you have to create a loop in main that will accomplish what the recursion is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (just removed the function combinationUtil and put it's content in
main method):

```
class permutation {


    public static void main (String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7};
    int r = 5;
    int n = arr.length;
    int data[]=new int[r];
    int start=0,end=n-1,index=0;

    if (index == r){
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++){
            System.out.print(data[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        return;
    }


    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, after compile file, it indicate that can't find the  "combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);" which is in   for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }